# Postgres Query with LIKE and EQUAL TO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query with LIKE and = conditions:

```
Model.where("extract(day from month) = ? OR lower(name) LIKE ?",params[:filter], "%#{params[:filter]}%".downcase )
```

I get return for the month value but i don't get any return for the name value.

so how can i use 'LIKE' and 'EQUAL TO' together in one query?

[EDIT] : when i use only the like statement it works fine.

Comment: Did you check, if there are any records getting returned when you only apply like query?

Answer (score 0):

We can definitely use like and equal to in the same query. Your query looks correct. Please check with hardcoded values to double check ex: Model.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%aManda%".downcase ) and then same for both conditions together.

Comment: when i use only one LIKE or multiple LIKE with OR/AND it works the problem is when i mix LIKE and EQUAL at the same time

Comment: Can you share exact query which does not work to demonstrate "i mix LIKE and EQUAL at the same time" ?

Comment: Model.where("extract(day from month) = ? OR lower(name) LIKE ?",params[:filter], "%#{params[:filter]}%".downcase )